# Solve for $\alpha$: $P = \int_{0}^{\alpha} \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{6}}{8\pi\sigma_{x}|x|}} e^{\frac{-\sqrt{3} |x|}{\sqrt{2}\sigma_{x}}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

So I need to solve the following for $\alpha$:

$$P = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\alpha} \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{6}}{8\pi\sigma_{x}|x|}} \exp \left( \frac{-\sqrt{3} |x|}{\sqrt{2}\sigma_{x}} \right) dx$$

If I could find the integral of the function, then I could find its inverse and apply it to $P$. However, I can't seem to do that. Does an analytical solution exist? Or will I have to do this numerically?

Comment: $P = A \text{erf}(B\sqrt{\alpha})$ for constants $A,B$, so it amounts to finding an inverse function for erf.

Comment: @2000 -- Just another constant.

Comment: @GEdgar. Are you sure? Isn't erf defined as $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\alpha} e^{-x^{2}} dx$ ? There is another $x$ in the denominator of the leading fraction, so I am not sure this is the same thing.

Comment: I did a change of variables to convert between yours and erf.

Comment: @GEdgar Hmm okay. I will have to figure out what you did and come back to you later.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** It's your integral
$$a\int_0^\alpha \frac{e^{-bx}}{\sqrt{x}}=a\sqrt{b}\int_0^\alpha \frac{e^{-bx}}{\sqrt{bx}}$$
where $a=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{6}}{8\pi\sigma_{x}}}$ and $b=e^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}\sigma_x}}$.

And $$\int \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t}} =\sqrt{\pi}\text{ erf}(\sqrt{t})$$ where $\text{erf}$ is [Error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Comment: +1. You should end up with $a = \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt 6}{8\pi\sigma_x}}$ and $\alpha = \sqrt{\frac 32}\frac{\alpha'}{\sigma_x}$ (where $\alpha'$ is the original $\alpha$).

Answer (score 0):

$$P =\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\alpha} \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{6}}{8\pi\sigma_{x}|x|}} \exp \left( \frac{-\sqrt{3} |x|}{\sqrt{2}\sigma_{x}} \right) dx$$ 
$$P =\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{6}}{8\pi\sigma_{x}}} \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\alpha} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \exp \left(-x \right)^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2} \sigma_{x}}} dx$$

Let:

$A = \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{6}}{8\pi\sigma_{x}}}$
$B = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2} \sigma_{x}}$

Then:

$$P = A\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\alpha} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \exp \left(-Bx \right)dx$$

Let:

$t^{2} = Bx$

Therefore:
$$\sqrt{x} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{B}} t$$
$$2t dt = Bdx \rightarrow \frac{2t}{B}dt = dx$$

Plugging In:

$$P =A\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\alpha} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{B}}t} \exp \left(-t^{2} \right)\frac{2t}{B}tdt$$

$$ P = \frac{2A}{\sqrt{B}}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\alpha^{'}}\exp \left(-t^{2} \right)dt$$

Where: $\alpha^{'} = \sqrt{B \alpha}$

Hence:

$$P = \frac{2A}{\sqrt{B}}erf(\sqrt{B} \sqrt{\alpha})$$
$$\alpha = \big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{B}} erf^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{B}P}{2A})\big)^{2}$$